# Calling Mathematica from R

Tags: r, wolfram-mathematica

Is there a way to call a Mathematica function from R? I'm using RStudio.

I'm trying to build a 'package' in Mathematica and call it from R. By the way, for this to work, would the person need to have mathematica installed?

I've seen packages written in C++, being called in R. The system didn't seem to have any c++ compiler/editor installed...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, Mathematica would need to be installed.  C++ compiles to a binary file that can be redistributed.  Unless there is a Mathematica "compile-to-executable" function you couldn't do the same thing with Mathematica, and even so you couldn't redistribute your package on CRAN.

Comment: See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115090/create-a-mathematica-function-that-can-be-called-from-r-or-matlab